# Unable to install hcxtools on my Raspberry Pi 4 with Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, raspberrypi

I wasn't able to install `hcxtools` on my Raspberry Pi 4 with Ubuntu.

When I try to install it I get the following:

```
# apt-get install hcxtools 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done 
E: Unable to locate package hcxtools
```

My architecture:

```
$ uname -m
aarch64
```

Comment: Please edit your question & add additional details there (you can edit your own question).  The package `hcxtools` is available for *groovy* & *hirsute* but not *focal* - https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=hcxtools&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all

Comment: FYI @karel, some of the answers in that question will create more problems for a non-amd64/i386 system, eg. as I understand it the accepted/most-upvoted answer will (if a country mirror is chosen) as it will take a ports.ubuntu.com pointed system and move to a mirror like [country].archive.ubuntu.com that may not mirror *arm64* for example

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to install the package by doing the following:

Download the latest Debian package manually:

```
wget http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/h/hcxtools/hcxtools_6.0.2-1_arm64.deb
```

Install the package manually:

```
sudo apt install ./hcxtools_6.0.2-1_arm64.deb
```

As far as I can see, [all dependencies should be ok](https://debian.pkgs.org/11/debian-main-arm64/hcxtools_6.0.2-1_arm64.deb.html) for this to work.

I've done this with several other packages, and everything is working perfectly. Just remember these packages has to be updated manually with the above method.

Answer (score 1):

`E: Unable to locate package <name>` means that `apt` can't find the package.

It's possible that you need to do an update to refresh your repo cache:

```
sudo  apt -y update
```

Then test with a known package (may already be installed):

```
sudo apt -y install lsof
```

Comment: hcxtools is not in the repo for Ubuntu 20.04 focal - it has to be installed manually.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to run `apt -y update` at the first place